# Developing with GAE - How much do I make myself dependent on Google?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Can an application developed on Google App Engine be run any where else without heavy modification? I mean at a cooperate/private server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing using GAE and GWT alone and not using any of the GAE specific services like mail, blobstore, memcache then you have nothing to worry about. You get tied down to GAE to the extent you use GAE services only. That said, you have to watch how you are accessing DataStore, as low level API's are going to lock you down to DataStore.

I haven't tried using AppScale and am assuming you were asking if you could host your web application on a standalone Tomcat/Glassfish server with a conventional RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

[AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) and [TypoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) are both projects which attempt to allow you to host your own App Engine compatible projects. Both are quite young and chasing the moving target that is GAE.

This question has [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633329/whats-the-next-steps-for-moving-from-appengine-to-full-django) [addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505265/how-difficult-is-it-to-migrate-away-from-google-app-engine) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634543/how-can-i-run-a-gae-application-on-a-private-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Appscale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/).

Please, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634543/how-can-i-run-a-gae-application-on-a-private-server).